# Openpyxl wrap_text

Tags: python, openpyxl

I used `openpyxl` to generate excel report. Some part of my code:

```
c = ws.cell(3, column=1, value="Наименование продукции:").font = Font(name='Times New Roman')
c.style = 'Content'
ws.cell(3, column=2, value=item.product_name).font = Font(name='Times New Roman')
ws.merge_cells(start_row=row, start_column=2, end_row=row, end_column=5)

content = NamedStyle(name="Content")
content.alignment = Alignment(wrap_text=True)
content.font = Font(name='Times New Roman')
```

But `Alignment(wrap_text=True)` didn't work. I think it is because of merge columns. On single column `wrap_text=True` works correct. How can I set dynamic `wrap_text` on merge columns?